# Can I temporarily stop to open other apps through my app for specific time?

Tags: android

i am developing phone addiction Android app
in this app i need a functionality don't open particular app for specific time

Answer (score 0):

Not without system level permissions, no.

Answer (score 0):

Device policy controller could probably solve your issue. [Look at this repo](http://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppRestrictionEnforcer)

The thing you are trying to archive is a really tricky one. I think there is no easy solution. Even custom launcher won't enforce rules to google play app through which you will be able to open applications.